# Send custom metrics to remote Prometheus from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, prometheus

I have a WebAPI where different client applications post some data regarding backlogs and queues in various applications. Basically, every 5 seconds I receive objects containing:

- Name
- Count
- TimeStamp
- Protocol

So for example:

- App1 Queue
- 53
- 2023-11-14 17:43:03
- AMQP

This data is stored in a database and now I've gotten a request to also send this data to a prometheus instance (which has remote_write enabled) that belongs to another team. I've tried finding how to go about this, but so far most of the docs I come upon suggest that I use my own Prometheus instance (which I don't have).

So, in short, is there any components or a way to send this data in a format that Prometheus would understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to make it in different way. Your app should provide interface which will be accessible by the prometheus server.

Try [prometheus-net](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net) library. It will create `/metrics` endpoint which can be readable by prometheus server.

In case if the prometheus team will refuse to connect to it, you can use [telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/) to read your endpoint and deliver metrics to their server via remote write. But it is better to convince your prometheus team to configure their server for reading.

One suggestion, use some non-standard port for the `/metrics` api and provide access to that port for the prometheus server only.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do is against [Remote-Write Specification](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/remote_write_spec/#background).

> The remote write protocol is **not** intended for use by applications to push metrics to Prometheus remote-write-compatible receivers. It is intended that a Prometheus remote-write-compatible sender scrapes instrumented applications or exporters and sends remote write messages to a server.

And this is the reason you can't find examples of this.

In your situations you should implement exporter, that will expose data present in your app in default Prometheus format. And then either configure existing Prometheus to scrape it, or create your own instance, that will scrape it, and will write to existing instance through remote write feature.

Edit: one more thing to consider. If **all** the data is stored in sql database, you might use any of existing sql exporter with simple list of predefined queries in it.